# How to test angular2 app who implements jquery library

Tags: jquery, angular, unit-testing, karma-runner

I have an angular2 components who encapsulate some jquery library ([timelineJS3](https://github.com/NUKnightLab/TimelineJS3)). All works well, but i need write tests. Specifically i want listen click events. To do this i used Renderer2. But it's doesn't work properly with karma.

See my code in plunkr https://embed.plnkr.co/7ROP9O2CgQolVeO5ItCb/

```
describe('- EventArray - ', () => {


let events = cosmological.events;

it('test click in next (idk how to fire jquery event)', async(() => {
  var i = 0;
  component.clicked.subscribe((ev: any) => {
    expect(ev.unique_id).toEqual(cosmological.events[i++].unique_id);
  });

  //init
  component.events = events;
  component.ngAfterViewInit();

  // trigger the click
  spyOn(component.clicked, 'emit');
  let button = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.tl-slidenav-next .tl-slidenav-content-container');
  button.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
  fixture.detectChanges();
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    expect(component.clicked.emit).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
}));


});
```

this piece of code doesn't fire event in karma. Idk why.

```
let button = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.tl-slidenav-next .tl-slidenav-content-container');
button.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should use `debugElement` of your `fixture` which will give you some [useful methods](https://angular.io/api/core/DebugElement) for testing. One is `triggerEventHandler` which will help you with your issue (and just to mention: `query` would be another method that you will probably want to use often since it's way more powerful than `querySelector` and will return again a `debugElement`).

```
let button: DebugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.tl-slidenav-next .tl-slidenav-content-container'));
button.triggerEventHandler('click', null); // where null is the event being passed if it's used in the listener
```

Hope it helps.